# makeMPIcluster under TORQUE: There are not enough slots available

Tags: r, mpi, hpc, torque

I am using a HPC with TORQUE/MOAB/RHEL 6.7.  The relevant lines in the PBS jobscript are

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=8,mem=12gb
module load r_3.2.0 
module load icc_14.0.3-ompi_1.8.3
mpirun -np 1\
  --mca mtl mx --mca pml cm --bind-to core --map-by core\
  Rscript >>dice.txt 2>&1 diceEstimate4i_parallel.R
```

In my R program I have:

```
library(Rmpi)
library(snow)
cl <- makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size())
```

I can see that the size of the MPI universe is correct (8 in this example) but the program fails with the error message "There are not enough slots available."  However, it works well if I ask for one less workers:

```
cl <- makeMPIcluster(mpi.universe.size() - 1)
```

But now I only have 7 workers (I have tested that), so one of the processor cores is not engaged in anything productive...

```
R CMD config CC
```

gives me just `mpicc`, I cannot find anything relevant in the rest of the config.

Any ideas how can I use all the allocated cpus?  I am beginner with mpirun and all that...  I works when on a different server w/o scheduler.  I have also been able to employ all allocated cpus with the `pbdMPI` package.

Comment: One guess, `mpirun -np 1` launched 1 processor in remoted node to run R script and it engaged 1 core, then in R core you create 8 again. So, don't have enough cores.

Comment: Thanks, I thought something along these lines as well..  But adding `includemaster=TRUE` to the `makeMPIcluster` did not seem to change anything.  I was also unable to locate any documentation for that option, or more detailed information how the MPI cluster will be set up.

Comment: could you try only launch rscript by pbs without mpirun or don't bind to core I guess?

Comment: I can try (when the current job finishes.)  I doubt about starting it w/o mpirun though, haven't tried it but google quickly shows up many problems arising with invoking R w/o mpirun.  Can try to both though.

Comment: Yes I will try to reproduce your case tomorrow. And I will be back to you for my results:)

Comment: Amazing!  It works without `mpirun`!  Just the `mpi.universe.size()` is wrong but I can get the right number from `PBS_NODEFILE`.  It works across several nodes, so it seems MPI is set up and running even without mpirun...  Would be nice if someone more experienced could comment on that.

Comment: job well done! congratulation!

Comment: What implementation and version of MPI are you using? In my experience with OpenMPI, you have to use mpirun in order to spawn workers on other nodes, but that may have changed.

Comment: R (3.2.0) is compiled with icc 14.0.3 using ompi 1.8.3.  But I suspect it is more about moab configuration--is the mpi communicator set up.  But I am new to clusters...

Answer (score 0):

So, the "official" answer.  Now I have tested the code many times and it works:

1. Invoke R in the jobscript without *mpirun*.
2. Detect the cluster size and create MPICluster.

The jobscript may look something like this:

```
module load r_3.2.0 
module load icc_14.0.3-ompi_1.8.3
Rscript program.R
```

and the R code the create the cluster:

```
nodefile <- Sys.getenv("PBS_NODEFILE")
nodes <- readLines(nodefile)
cl <- makeMPIcluster(length(nodes), includemaster=TRUE)
```